# I am wondering how to make a clock timer in react native that starts from 00:00:00

Tags: react-native, timer

I want to make a clock timer that starts on page load. like below

00 m: 06 s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start a setInterval in the componentDidMount and update the state every second.

```
  state = {
    time: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prev => {
        return {
          time: prev.time + 1,
        };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

and extract seconds,minutes,hours

```
const { time } = this.state;
const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor((time - hours * 3600) / 60);
const seconds = time - minutes * 60 - hours * 3600;
```

Here is an expo [demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/timer)

Comment: I need to stop this timer if there is no internet